# How do you pass a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, member

I am trying to pass a member function within a class to a function that takes a member function class pointer.  The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to properly do this within the class using the this pointer.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Here is a copy of the class that is passing the member function:

```
class testMenu : public MenuScreen{
public:

bool draw;

MenuButton<testMenu> x;

testMenu():MenuScreen("testMenu"){
    x.SetButton(100,100,TEXT("buttonNormal.png"),TEXT("buttonHover.png"),TEXT("buttonPressed.png"),100,40,&this->test2);

    draw = false;
}

void test2(){
    draw = true;
}
};
```

The function x.SetButton(...) is contained in another class, where "object" is a template.

```
void SetButton(int xPos, int yPos, LPCWSTR normalFilePath, LPCWSTR hoverFilePath, LPCWSTR pressedFilePath, int Width, int Height, void (object::*ButtonFunc)()) {

    BUTTON::SetButton(xPos, yPos, normalFilePath, hoverFilePath, pressedFilePath, Width, Height);

    this->ButtonFunc = &ButtonFunc;
}
```

If anyone has any advice on how I can properly send this function so that I can use it later.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To call a member function by pointer, you need two things: A pointer to the object and a pointer to the function. You need both in `MenuButton::SetButton()`

```
template <class object>
void MenuButton::SetButton(int xPos, int yPos, LPCWSTR normalFilePath,
        LPCWSTR hoverFilePath, LPCWSTR pressedFilePath,
        int Width, int Height, object *ButtonObj, void (object::*ButtonFunc)())
{
  BUTTON::SetButton(xPos, yPos, normalFilePath, hoverFilePath, pressedFilePath, Width, Height);

  this->ButtonObj = ButtonObj;
  this->ButtonFunc = ButtonFunc;
}
```

Then you can invoke the function using both pointers:

```
((ButtonObj)->*(ButtonFunc))();
```

Don't forget to pass the pointer to your object to `MenuButton::SetButton()`:

```
testMenu::testMenu()
  :MenuScreen("testMenu")
{
  x.SetButton(100,100,TEXT("buttonNormal.png"), TEXT("buttonHover.png"),
        TEXT("buttonPressed.png"), 100, 40, this, test2);
  draw = false;
}
```

Comment: `A pointer to the class` - should that be `A pointer to the object`?

Comment: Thanks so much. Couldn't figure out that the syntax is something like ((ButtonObj)->*(ButtonFunc))()

Answer (score 15):

I'd strongly recommend `boost::bind` and `boost::function` for anything like this.

See [Pass and call a member function (boost::bind / boost::function?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245072/pass-and-call-a-member-function-boostbind-boostfunction)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a quite old topic. But there is an elegant way to handle this with c++11

```
#include <functional>
```

declare your function pointer like this

```
typedef std::function<int(int,int) > Max;
```

declare your the function your pass this thing into

```
void SetHandler(Max Handler);
```

suppose you pass a normal function to it you can use it like normal

```
SetHandler(&some function);
```

suppose you have a member function

```
class test{
public:
  int GetMax(int a, int b);
...
}
```

in your code you can pass it using `std::placeholders` like this

```
test t;
Max Handler = std::bind(&test::GetMax,&t,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2);
some object.SetHandler(Handler);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You've a type though: it's `std::placeholders`, plural.

Answer (score 5):

Would you not be better served to use standard OO. Define a contract (virtual class) and implement that in your own class, then just pass a reference to your own class and let the receiver call the contract function.

Using your example (I've renamed the 'test2' method to 'buttonAction'):

```
class ButtonContract
{
  public:
    virtual void buttonAction();
}


class testMenu : public MenuScreen, public virtual ButtonContract
{
  public:
    bool draw;
    MenuButton<testMenu> x;

    testMenu():MenuScreen("testMenu")
    {
      x.SetButton(100,100,TEXT("buttonNormal.png"), 
              TEXT("buttonHover.png"), 
              TEXT("buttonPressed.png"), 
              100, 40, &this);
      draw = false;
    }

    //Implementation of the ButtonContract method!
    void buttonAction()
    {
      draw = true;
    }
};
```

In the receiver method, you store the reference to a ButtonContract, then when you want to perform the button's action just call the 'buttonAction' method of that stored ButtonContract object.

Comment: The problem is that the sheer number of different functions that can be called by a button, would make this task very tedious.  There are probably 75 to 100 functions that a button can possibly call.

Comment: A testMenu *hasA* ButtonContract (or many of them), rather than an *isA* relationship. This approach makes it hard to implement two buttons with the same action, or buttons with different actions.

Answer (score 2):

In the rare case that you happen to be developing with Borland C++Builder and don't mind writing code specific to that development environment (that is, code that won't work with other C++ compilers), you can use the __closure keyword.  I found a [small article about C++Builder closures](http://www.drbob42.com/cbuilder/lstfnd15.htm).  They're intended primarily for use with Borland VCL.

Comment: That's a rather... obscure solution.

Comment: Yup, it's obscure. :)  There's Delphi and C++Builder legacy code floating out there in corporate land, though.  Best to be thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Others have told you how to do it correctly. But I'm surprised no-one told you this code is actually dangerous:

```
this->ButtonFunc = &ButtonFunc;
```

Since ButtonFunc is a parameter, it will go out of scope when the function returns. You are taking its address. You will get a value of type `void (object::**ButtonFunc)()` (*pointer to a pointer to a member function*) and assign it to this->ButtonFunc. At the time you would try to use this->ButtonFunc you would try to access the storage of the (now not existing anymore) local parameter, and your program would probably crash.

I agree with Commodore's solution. But you have to change his line to

```
((ButtonObj)->*(ButtonFunc))();
```

since ButtonObj is a *pointer* to object.