# Passing C++ function pointer to C function

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass a C++ member function to a C API as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517484/how-can-i-pass-a-c-member-function-to-a-c-api-as-a-parameter)

Hi I have class with a C function expecting a call back as follows: 
void fun_c(void * (*ptr)(void *)).

Now I want to send C++ method to c function, can anyone tell me how to do this:

```
class ClassA{
  method1(){
    func(ClassA::func);
  }
  void * func(void * arg){
  }
}
```

Can anyone will this work.

Comment: There's a few oddities in your example code that make it harder to follow - `method1()` doesn't have a return type but isn't a constructor/destructor. `func` in `method1` will be the same as `ClassA::func`, passing a function a pointer to itself is weird. The signature for `func` doesn't actually take a function pointer, it takes a `void*`, which isn't legal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an instance function because the C code will not have an instance available or even the knowledge of what to do with one. You need to use a static function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically usually cases like these you can declare

```
 void MyCallBack( void* arg )
 {
    ClassA * p = static_cast<ClassA*> (arg);
    //Invoke any member functions of p as needed
    p->HandleCallBack();
 }
```

This is based on the assumption that the call back function calls you back with some data* pointer that you give it. And you pass this when you setup your call back

Comment: And technically it also needs `extern "C"`, although in practice C++ implementations do use the same calling convention for free C++ functions as for C functions. Sadly it seems in this case the C API is badly-designed, since `fun_c` doesn't take a data pointer, just the function pointer. So the questioner is out of luck.

Comment: sorry my mistake : class ClassA{
  method1(){
    func(ClassA::func);
  }
  void * func(void * arg){
  }
}