# Passing any generic function as a C++ argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments, member

I'm trying to pass any generic function as an argument in a C++ function. As an extra layer of fun, the function is going to reside in its own separate class. In this particular case, they will all take no arguments and return `void`. This includes members of any generic class.

My current code reads like:

```
class functionsFedHere {
public:
    void (*callback)();
    functionsFedHere(void(*)());
}

functionsFedHere::functionsFedHere (void(*callbackFunction)()) {
    callback = callbackFunction;
}

void fn1() { cout<<"Fn1"<<endl; }

class myClass {
public:
    int i;
    void fn2() { cout<<i<<endl; }
}

class myOtherClass {
public:
    string j;
    void fn3() { cout<<j<<endl; }
}

int main() {

    // Initialise some objects
    myClass b;
    b.i = 2;

    myOtherClass c;
    c.j = "some text";

    // Works fine with non-member functions
    functionsFedHere objectA(fn1);
    objectA.callback();

    // Doesn't work with member functions
    functionsFedHere objectB(b.fn2);
    functionsFedHere objectC(c.fn3);
}
```

I've seen solutions like [a forwarding function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument), or [boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245072/pass-and-call-a-member-function-boostbind-boostfunction), but as far as I can tell, I don't think these solutions will fit?

It's also worth noting that eventually I'd like to pass member functions by way of an array of pointers. For example, if `myPointer[]` is an array of pointers to objects of class `myClass`, then it would be nice to be able to write something like:

```
functionsFedHere objectD(myPointer[0]->fn2);
```

**EDIT**: Apparently I wasn't clear enough. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/c-function-pointer-to-member-function) is not an appropriate answer, because I'm looking to pass both member and non-member functions as arguments (whereas the suggested answer is setting up a member pointer to a function that is a member of the same class).

I don't think that the forward function example will work, because the forwarding function assumes a single class type, where I'd like to pass an object of generic class.

`boost::bind` could well be the answer; I'm just unfamiliar with it. Can anyone point me towards some newbie-friendly reading material?

**EDIT 2**: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm programming on a device that is **pre-C++11**.

Comment: _"I don't think these solutions will fit?"_ Why??

Comment: boost::bind is the solution, unless you can define the functions myClass::fn2 and myOtherClass::fn3 as static.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Original post has been edited to clarify why the suggested solution is not the answer.

Comment: @Alec I'd say you can use the `boost` solution likewise for pre-C++11 compilers. Otherwise you'll need to brew your own stuff as proposed in the answer here. `myPointer[0]->fn2` simply doesn't yield a member function pointer, and never will, period! And that's what's explained in detail in the duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::function`:

```
class functionsFedHere {
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> Func;
    Func callback;
    functionsFedHere(Func callback_) : callback(callback_) {}
};

void fn1() { cout<<"Fn1"<<endl; }

class myClass {
public:
    int i;
    void fn2() { cout<<i<<endl; }
};

class myOtherClass {
public:
    string j;
    void fn3() { cout<<j<<endl; }
};

class callableClass {
public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "in callableClass" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {

    // Initialise some objects
    myClass b;
    b.i = 2;

    myOtherClass c;
    c.j = "some text";

    // Works fine with non-member functions
    functionsFedHere objectA(fn1);
    objectA.callback();

    // Works with member functions now
    functionsFedHere objectB(std::bind(&myClass::fn2, b));
    objectB.callback();
    functionsFedHere objectC(std::bind(&myOtherClass::fn3, c));
    objectC.callback();

    // Works with lambdas as well
    functionsFedHere objectLambda([]() { std::cout << "in lambda" << std::endl; });
    objectLambda.callback();

    // Works also with classes with overloaded operator()
    functionsFedHere(callableClass()).callback();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show a use of lambdas with one of those member functions and you'll earn an upvote from me.

Comment: @AntonSavin this looks like a beautiful solution, but I forgot to mention that I'm pre-C++11.

Comment: @Alec in that case you can use `boost::function` together with `boost::bind` - it's essentially the same.