# Get a pointer to an object's member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member

I have class like so

```cpp
class some_class
{
public:
    some_type some_value;
    int some_function(double *a, double *b, int c, int d, void *e);
};
```

Inside `some_function`, I use `some_values` from `some_class` object to get a result.

So, I have a concrete object, and I want to get a pointer to this object `some_function`.

Is it possible? I can't use `some_fcn_ptr`, because, the result of this function depends on the concrete `some_value` of an object.

How can I get a pointer to `some_function` of an object?

```cpp
typedef  int (Some_class::*some_fcn_ptr)(double*, double*, int, int, void*);
```

Comment: You are talking about [pointer-to-member-functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer for details. You can't get function pointer for some concrete object, you need pointer to object and pointer to member function to call method of some object.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot, at least it won't be only a pointer to a function.

Member functions are common for all instances of this class. All member functions have the implicit (first) parameter, `this`. In order to call a member function for a specific instance you need a pointer to this member function and this instance.

```
class Some_class
{
public:
    void some_function() {}
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (Some_class::*Some_fnc_ptr)();
    Some_fnc_ptr fnc_ptr = &Some_class::some_function;

    Some_class sc;

    (sc.*fnc_ptr)();

    return 0;
}
```

More info here in [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Using **Boost** this can look like (C++11 provides similar functionality):

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

boost::function<void(Some_class*)> fnc_ptr = boost::bind(&Some_class::some_function, _1);
Some_class sc;
fnc_ptr(&sc);
```

C++11's lambdas:

```
#include <functional>

Some_class sc;
auto f = [&sc]() { sc.some_function(); };
f();
// or
auto f1 = [](Some_class& sc) { sc.some_function(); };
f1(sc);
```

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't get a pointer to a C++ class method (unless the method is declared static). The reason is that a class method always has the pointer `this`, a pointer to the class instance. But were you to call the method through a pointer, that pointer could not encapsulate the `this` pointer, and then then there would be no instance attached, and therefore this behavior is not legal.

Answer (score 12):

You may write some kind of Wrapper which is able to use both function or method as parameter.

I used following classes for launching functions (it was used in one my SDL program):

```
class CallbackFunction {
public:
    // Constructor, copy constructor and destructor

    virtual int execute( SDL_keysym* keysym) const;
    virtual int operator()( SDL_keysym* keysym) const;

protected:
    int( *callback)( SDL_keysym*));
}

int CallbackFunction::execute( SDL_keysym* keysym) const{
    return callback(keysym);
}

int CallbackFunction::operator()( SDL_keysym* keysym) const{
    return callback( keysym);
}
```

And this extension for "methods":

```
template<class T>
class CallbackMethod : public CallbackFunction {
public:
    // Constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    CallbackMethod( T *object, int(T::*callback)( SDL_keysym* keysym));

    int execute( SDL_keysym* keysym) const;
    int operator()(SDL_keysym* keysym) const;

protected:
    T *object;
    int(T::*method)( SDL_keysym* keysym);
};

// Object initialization (constructor)
template<class T>
CallbackMethod<T>::CallbackMethod( T *object, int(T::*callback)( SDL_keysym* keysym)):
    CallbackFunction( NULL),object(object),method(callback){
}


// Responsible for executing
template<class T>
int CallbackMethod<T>::execute( SDL_keysym* keysym) const {
    return (object->*method)(keysym);
}
template<class T>
int CallbackMethod<T>::operator()( keysym) const {
    return (object->*method)( keysym);
}
```

And then use it as:

```
CallbackFunction *callback;
callback = new CallbackFunction( myFunction);
callback = new CallbackMethod<A>( instanceOfA, instanceOfA::myMethod);
callback = new CallbackMethod<B>( instanceOfB, instanceOfB::myMethod);
...
callback( keysym);
```

I found macro as this:

```
CALLBACK(object,method) new CallbackMethod<typeof(*object)>( object, &method)
```

really useful

Answer (score 5):

While not exactly what you requested, if you can use C++11 the following might nevertheless suit your needs (untested):

```
std::function<int(double*, double*, int, int, void*)>
  some_function_of(Some_class& obj)
{
  return [&](double* a, double* b, int c, int d, void* e){
    return obj.some_func(a, b, c, d, e); };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library. I included "boost/bind.hpp" in my code. Then a method named "fn" can be defined as

auto fn = boost::bind(ClassName::methodName, classInstanceName, boost::placeholders::_1);