# c++ Function member pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I have read several posts about this, but can't seem to find exactly what i am looking for with example code if anyone could give me some help i would highly appreciate it.

in my header i have:

```
void addEvent(void (*func)(Pack  *));

void triggerEvents(Pack * );

std::list<void(*)(Pack *)> eventList;
```

and in cpp file

```
void DNetwork::addEvent(void (*func)(Pack *)){
    eventList.push_back(func);
}

void DNetwork::triggerEvents(Pack * pack){
    for (std::list<void (*)( Pack *)>::iterator it = eventList.begin(); it !=         eventList.end() ;it++ ){
        (*it)(pack);
    } 
}
```

This works fine with free functions, but when i try to add a member function to this list i get an error. Does anyone know how to store a member function (from random class objects) inside a pointer?

Comment: Yap: `ReturnType (TheClass::*memberPointer)(arguments, ...) = &TheClass::aMemberFunction;`

Comment: See C++ FAQ section 33: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: Yes, but i want to be able to store function pointers from different classes as well. Is it possible to have a parent class for the class i want to use which can take the functions so that the list will be: something like this std::list<void(*)(ParentClass::Pack *)> eventList;

Comment: Take a look at std::function<void(ParentClass::Pack *)>

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For member function you need a bind. A member function is a "normal function" that has an implicit parameter of its class. So you need a binder. If you use c++11 you can use std::bind and std::function or you can use boost::bind and boost::function for non c++11 code.

```
typedef std::function< void ( Pack* ) > MyFunction;
void addEvent( MyFunction f );
void triggerEvents( Pack* );
std::list< MyFunction > eventList;

void DNetwork::addEvent( MyFunction f )
{
    eventList.push_back( f );
}

void DNetwork::triggerEvents( Pack *pack )
{
    for ( auto it = eventList.begin(); it != eventList.end(); it++ )
    {
        (*it)(pack);
    } 
}
```

Now if I have the class A with the method `doA( Pack* )` I will write:

```
A a;
Pack pack;
DNetwork d;
d.addEvent( std::bind( &A::doA, &a, &pack ) );
```

Or even better you can use Boost.Signal or you can use the [Publisher/Subcriber Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe)

**Edit** 
As @DavidRodríguez-dribeas suggest: The bind should not take the &pack argument, as the argument to the member function is provided at the place of call in triggerEvents. The correct way is:

```
A a;
Pack pack;
DNetwork d;
d.addEvent( std::bind( &A::doA, &a, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
d.triggerEvents( &pack );
```

Comment: The bind should not take the `&pack` argument, as the argument to the member function is provided at the place of call in `triggerEvents`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You are right. It must be `d.addEvent( std::bind( &A::doA, &a, std::placeholders::_1 ) );`

Answer (score 3):

The *simple* solution is using type erasure on the function/function pointer type, for which the easier way is just using `std::function<>`:

```
std::list<std::function<void (Pack*)>;
```

Then you can initialize the `function` objects with either a free function or a member function (by means of `std::bind` to bind the member-function with an object on which to call it) or even function objects (types that offer an `operator()`).

Answer (score -1):

You could do an overload such as:

```
std::list<void(*)(Pack *)> eventList;
void addEvent(void (*func)(Pack  *));
template<typename T>
void addEvent(void (T::*func)(Pack  *));
namespace Abstraction {
    template<typename T>
    void abstractlyAddEvent( T, std::list<void(*)(Pack *)> *eventList );
}
```

Comment: there is not need to complicate things so much! just a bind!

Comment: @elvis.dukaj No need to mark me down, my solution works just as well. :-(

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding your problem you get the error when you try to add a function to the list in addEvent?

If you're adding a pointer to a **non-static** member function of a class ensure it has the right syntax... for example a function pointer to a a member function in TestClass would look like:

```
void * (TestClass:: *) ()
```

Comment: This not resolve the problem. We need just a simple way to bind to ordinary function and method. So it's juast function + bind