# How do I use a method as an argument for another method?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
  void print(std::function<void (void)> f){
    f();
    std::cout << "!";
  }
 void sayHello(){
   std::cout << "Hello";
 }
public:
  void tell(){
    print(sayHello);
  }
};

int main(){
  auto foo = Foo();
  foo.tell(); // 'Foo::sayHello': function call missing argument list; use '&Foo::sayHello' to create a pointer to member
}
```

I am getting the error `C3867: 'Foo::sayHello': function call missing argument list; use '&Foo::sayHello' to create a pointer to member`. If I use `&Foo::sayHello` then I'll get a bunch of templating errors.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/calling-member-function-pointer-c

Comment: Please read this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass a member function as argument, however a member function must be called on an object instance.

A possible solution is the following:

```
void tell(){
    print(std::bind(&Foo::sayHello, this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`sayHello` is a non-static member function, so it has an implicit first argument, the `this` pointer. The simplest way to get your code to work is to use a lambda expression that captures the `this` pointer.

```
void tell(){
  print([this]{sayHello();});
}
```

Another option is `std::bind`

```
void tell(){
  print(std::bind(&Foo::sayHello, this));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A member function has an additional parameter: the `this` pointer. You are just assuming the declaration of the function has none

```
void (void)
```

The [bind()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function can help you bind that pointer into it and return an object suitable for a `std::function` wrapper

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
  void print(std::function<void (void)> f){
    f();
    std::cout << "!";
  }
  void sayHello(){
    std::cout << "Hello";
  }
public:
  void tell(){
    print(std::bind(&Foo::sayHello, this));
  }
};

int main(){
  auto foo = Foo();
  foo.tell();
}
```