# Passing a member function of a class to a parameter outside the class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

How do you pass a member function of a class as a parameter to another member function of another class?

```
class theSecondClass
{
    public:
    void theFunctionReceiver(void (theFirstClass::*Function)(void));
    {
         // This part is wrong. "Operand of * must be a pointer"
         (*Function)(); 
    }
}

class theFirstClass
{
    public:
    theSecondClass * SecondClassInstance;
    void theFunctiontoPass(void)
    {
        printf("It worked \n");
        return;
    }
    void theFunctiontoCall(void)
    {
        SecondClassInstance->theFunctionReceiver(theFunctiontoPass);
    }
};
```

Take the assumption that `theSecondClass` and `theFirstClass` are both made already. I'm calling `theFirstClass->theFunctiontoCall()` from somewhere.

I don't get it. When I pass it in, isn't it pass in as a pointer?

I've taken a look at several similar threads around, but I don't understand them fully.
I'm using VS 2013, basic compiler.

Comment: You need an instance of `theFirstClass` so you can invoke the function like so `(instanceOftheFirstClass->*Function)()` - assuming `instanceOftheFirstClass` is a pointer. Consider using `std::function` and `std::bind` instead.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem : what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @quantdev XY problem? What is that? What I'm trying to do is for opengl camera creation. I want to put everything I'm rendering into a function of my draw class, and pass that function into my camera so that it can draw it in Third Person Camera.

Comment: check this may be it will give idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer

Comment: @Eddie If I'm going to pass in a reference to my class, why would I even need to pass it the function? Couldn't I just call it with, in the case of the link, ButtonObj->Buttonfunc();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this statement:

```
SecondClassInstance->theFunctionReceiver(theFunctiontoPass);
```

What you presumably meant was:

```
SecondClassInstance->theFunctionReceiver(&theFunctiontoPass);
```

Which should give you a compiler warning that it's an unqualified member reference, which would point out to you that what you are actually writing is:

```
SecondClassInstance->theFunctionReceiver(&theFirstClass::theFunctiontoPass);
```

You are getting a pointer to a member function *on the class definition*.  The "this" is not implicit or included in the package.  The only way you're going to be able to call it *without a class instance* is if it is static.  (In which case it won't type-check as a member function...it will just be an ordinary function pointer.)

> If I'm going to pass in a reference to my class, why would I even need to pass it the function? Couldn't I just call it with, in the case of the link, ButtonObj->Buttonfunc();

The only reason you would use pointers to member functions is to get some kind of abstraction, where one piece of code can call a member function it doesn't need to explicitly name.  If you're okay with `theSecondClass::theFunctionReceiver` knowing the name of `theFirstClass::theFunctionToPass` and the identity of `theFirstClass`...then sure, just pass a reference to an instance of theFirstClass and call the method explicitly.

You *might* want a situation where `theSecondClass` is going to call any one of a number of member functions on `theFirstClass` with matching signatures...it just doesn't want to hard-code which one.  In that case, then passing a pair of a class reference and a member function can be done.  You seem to suspect this doesn't come up too often as useful, and you would be right.  Every year I have to go back and look up the syntax for how to call pointers-to-members on a class, because it almost never comes up except in StackOverflow questions:

[How to call through a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/calling-member-function-pointer-c)

More likely what you want (and what people asking those SO questions actually want) is to separate concerns so that `theSecondClass` has a hook to execute *something*, but doesn't need to know about `theFirstClass` at all.  Look into **lambdas**, **std::function**, and **std::bind** for generalized solutions which you may be able to experiment with to your satisfaction.

Here is an example to show you what that would look like to conveniently wrap up the call abstractly into a std::function.  It makes a function object on the spot, that captures the enclosing `this` pointer so that when it is invoked it calls the method on the object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class theSecondClass {
public:
    void theFunctionReceiver(std::function<void()> const & Function) {
         Function(); 
    }
};

class theFirstClass {
private:
    theSecondClass * SecondClassInstance;
public:
    void theFunctiontoPass() {
        std::cout << "It worked\n";
    }
    void theFirstClass::theFunctiontoCall() {
        SecondClassInstance->theFunctionReceiver(
            [this]() {theFunctiontoPass();}
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    theFirstClass tfc;
    tfc.theFunctiontoCall();
}
```

Note this is C++11, which I suggest using if you're not already.  Less convenient notations and mechanisms exist in C++98, though.

This corrects problems with your code that go beyond the issue you mention.  Please review writing a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It should be possible to paste your provided code into a compiler and see *only* the error you wish to discuss.

- This adds semicolons after the ends of class definitions
- This removes the semicolon after method declarations when you are supplying bodies in the class
- You needed various forward definitions to get it to work as you had it, this doesn't require them
- When a function takes no parameters, it's customary to define as `void foo()` not `void foo(void)`.  `return;` as the last line of a function returning no value is kind of superfluous as well.
- Avoid writing new C++ code using printf, [learn iostreams](http://blog.hostilefork.com/iostreams-reexamined/)
- Bias member variables to being private or protected.
- On StackOverflow code samples try and keep them short and not need scroll bars; it's best to not give opening braces their own line (most of the time)

While naming is subjective, I'd suggest that giving your class names initial caps is a better idea than giving variables initial caps.