# How to pass an object function as a template argument

Tags: c++

```
bool HuffmanNode::Compare::operator()(const HuffmanNode &n1, const HuffmanNode &n2) const
{
    if (n1.frequency == n2.frequency) {
        return lessThan ? n1.character < n2.character : n1.character >= n2.character;
    } else {
        return lessThan ? n1.frequency < n2.frequency : n1.frequency >= n2.frequency;
    }
}

bool HuffmanNode::Compare::operator()(const HuffmanNode *n1, const HuffmanNode *n2) const
{
    return operator()(*n1, *n2);
}
```

Here I have a compare function from a compare object that is within another object (HuffmanNode).
I want to pass the compare function to another object through a template:

```
HeapQueue<HuffmanNode, HuffmanNode::Compare> queue;
```

This doesn't seem to work and I've even tried using the operator function.

What is the proper format for this? Thanks.

Here is my compiler error

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1826:31: error: 
      no matching constructor for initialization of 'HuffmanNode'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1718:18: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>::construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1561:14: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>
      >::__construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, _Tp*, _Args...>(),
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1030:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>
      >::construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
        __alloc_traits::construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_));
                        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1121:9: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<HuffmanNode,
      std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode> >::__construct_at_end' requested here
        __construct_at_end(__n);
        ^
./HeapQueue.hpp:25:26: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<HuffmanNode, std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode> >::vector'
      requested here
  VectorCompleteTree() : V(1) {}
                         ^
./HeapQueue.hpp:46:7: note: in instantiation of member function
      'VectorCompleteTree<HuffmanNode>::VectorCompleteTree' requested here
class HeapQueue
      ^
./HuffmanBase.hpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy
      constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class HuffmanNode {
      ^
./HuffmanBase.hpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move
      constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
./HuffmanBase.hpp:11:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 0 were provided
  HuffmanNode(char c, size_t f) : HuffmanNode(c, f, nullptr, nullptr, nu...
  ^
./HuffmanBase.hpp:10:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 5
      arguments, but 0 were provided
  HuffmanNode(char c, size_t f, HuffmanNode *p, HuffmanNode *l, HuffmanN...
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613214/passing-functions-as-arguments-in-c

Comment: How do I use object functions as a template argument?

Comment: What you can pass as non-type template parameters is limited to some allowed cases. According to [this cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) one of the allowed cases is a pointer to function or pointer to member function. That is probably your best bet.

Comment: @darcamo Im not allowed to change anything from the first code snippet for this assignment

Comment: The error message says that `HuffmanBase` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: The default constructor of `VectorCompleteTree` is constructing a `std::vector<HuffmanNode>` with one element. That one element is being default constructed. The problem is that `HuffmanNode` doesn't have a default constructor so this fails. It has nothing to do with `HuffmanNode::Compare`.

Comment: Just added a default constructor and it worked without errors, however that HuffmanBase class is provided by my instructor and im not allowed to change that file. Is there a workaround to not having a default constructor? My program compiles fine without this line: HeapQueue<HuffmanNode, HuffmanNode::Compare> queue;

Comment: @Dp4897 Are you allowed to change `VectorCompleteTree` or `HeapQueue`? Maybe there's a different constructor of `HeapQueue` (other than the default one) that you could use.

Comment: If you can't change anything then maybe you could try `HeapQueue<std::unique_ptr<HuffmanNode>, HuffmanNode::Compare>`. If that doesn't work (because something is trying to copy the `std::unique_ptr<HuffmanNode>`) then you could try `HeapQueue<std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode>, HuffmanNode::Compare>`

Comment: @Dp4897 We might be able to help you if you give us more information about what you have available (`HeapQueue`, `VectorCompleteTree` and `HuffmanNode`) and precisely what you're allowed to change.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the bottom of the error message, the compiler is trying to do this `HuffmanNode{}` but failing because `HuffmanNode` doesn't have a default constructor. The key here is `but 0 were provided`.

```
./HuffmanBase.hpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy
      constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class HuffmanNode {
      ^
./HuffmanBase.hpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move
      constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
./HuffmanBase.hpp:11:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 0 were provided
  HuffmanNode(char c, size_t f) : HuffmanNode(c, f, nullptr, nullptr, nu...
  ^
./HuffmanBase.hpp:10:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 5
      arguments, but 0 were provided
  HuffmanNode(char c, size_t f, HuffmanNode *p, HuffmanNode *l, HuffmanN...
  ^
```

The default constructor of `HeapQueue` is invoking the default constructor of `VectorCompleteTree<HuffmanNode>`.

```
./HeapQueue.hpp:46:7: note: in instantiation of member function
      'VectorCompleteTree<HuffmanNode>::VectorCompleteTree' requested here
class HeapQueue
```

The default constructor of `VectorCompleteTree<HuffmanNode>` is constructing a `std::vector<HuffmanNode>` with one element. This one element needs to be default constructed.

```
./HeapQueue.hpp:25:26: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<HuffmanNode, std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode> >::vector'
      requested here
  VectorCompleteTree() : V(1) {}
```

`std::vector<HuffmanNode>` is trying to default construct a `HuffmanNode` but can't.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1826:31: error: 
      no matching constructor for initialization of 'HuffmanNode'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1718:18: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>::construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1561:14: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>
      >::__construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, _Tp*, _Args...>(),
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1030:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode>
      >::construct<HuffmanNode>' requested here
        __alloc_traits::construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_));
                        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1121:9: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<HuffmanNode,
      std::__1::allocator<HuffmanNode> >::__construct_at_end' requested here
        __construct_at_end(__n);
```

It's all there in the error message! The simple solution would be do give `HuffmanNode` a default constructor.